# How to get all Display text from a webpage in C#

Tags: c#, html

Hi I am working on data scraping application in C#.

Actually I want to get all the Display text but not the html tags.

Here's My code

```
HtmlWeb web  = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = web.
   Load(@"http://dawateislami.net/books/bookslibrary.do#!section:bookDetail_521.tr");
string str =  doc.DocumentNode.InnerText;
```

This inner html is returning some tags and scripts as well but I want to only get the Display text that's visible to user.
Please help me.
Thanks

Comment: could you give an example of out input and output?

Comment: out put is like this <!--some text--!>

but I want only text

Answer (score 2):

[I believe this will solve ur problem][1]

Method 1 – In Memory Cut and Paste

Use WebBrowser control object to process the web page, and then copy the text from the control…

Use the following code to download the web page:
Collapse | Copy Code

```
//Create the WebBrowser control
WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowser();
//Add a new event to process document when download is completed   
wb.DocumentCompleted +=
    new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(DisplayText);
//Download the webpage
wb.Url = urlPath;
```

Use the following event code to process the downloaded web page text:
Collapse | Copy Code

```
private void DisplayText(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
WebBrowser wb = (WebBrowser)sender;
wb.Document.ExecCommand(“SelectAll”, false, null);
wb.Document.ExecCommand(“Copy”, false, null);
textResultsBox.Text = CleanText(Clipboard.GetText());
}
```

Method 2 – In Memory Selection Object

This is a second method of processing the downloaded web page text. It seems to take just a bit longer (very minimal difference). However, it avoids using the clipboard and the limitations associated with that.
Collapse | Copy Code

```
private void DisplayText(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{   //Create the WebBrowser control and IHTMLDocument2
WebBrowser wb = (WebBrowser)sender;
IHTMLDocument2 htmlDocument =
wb.Document.DomDocument as IHTMLDocument2;
//Select all the text on the page and create a selection object
wb.Document.ExecCommand(“SelectAll”, false, null);
IHTMLSelectionObject currentSelection = htmlDocument.selection;
//Create a text range and send the range’s text to your text box
IHTMLTxtRange range = currentSelection.createRange() as IHTMLTxtRange
textResultsBox.Text = range.text;
}
```

Method 3 – The Elegant, Simple, Slower XmlDocument Approach

A good friend shared this example with me. I am a huge fan of simple, and this example wins the simplicity contest hands down. It was unfortunately very slow compared to the other two approaches.

The XmlDocument object will load / process HTML files with only 3 simple lines of code:
Collapse | Copy Code

```
XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
document.Load(“www.yourwebsite.com”);
string allText = document.InnerText;
```

There you have it! Three simple ways to scrape only displayed text from web pages with no external “packages” involved.
Packages

Answer (score 0):

To remove javascript and css:

```
foreach(var script in doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("script").ToArray())
    script.Remove();
foreach(var style in doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("style").ToArray())
    style.Remove();
```

To remove comments (untested):

```
foreach(var comment in doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("//comment()").ToArray())
    comment.Remove()
```

Comment: it's not working :)

bye the way what is this.
can you recommend another solution

Comment: I've added a line for removing comments as well. It would be helpful if you were more specific about what exactly appears that you don't want

Comment: To array method is not supporting

Answer (score 0):

For removing all html tags from a string you can use:

```
String output = inputString.replaceAll("<[^>]*>", "");
```

For removing a specific tag:

```
String output = inputString.replaceAll("(?i)<td[^>]*>", "");
```

Hope it helps :)