# how to convert html to plain text c#?

Tags: c#, html

i am trying to get plain text from html website but i am getting html code instead of plain text.for example  < b >  hello <  /b> < p > its me < / p> How can i convert  it to   hello its me . Any help is very much appreciated! here is my code .

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
 using System.Net;
 using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

 namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
 {
   public partial class Form1 : Form
   {
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        HttpWebRequest myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(""https://www.dailyfx.com/real-time-news");
        myRequest.Method = "GET";
        WebResponse myResponse = myRequest.GetResponse();
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(myResponse.GetResponseStream(), System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
        string result = sr.ReadToEnd();




        textBox1.Text = result;
        sr.Close();
        myResponse.Close();
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by Plain Text?

Comment: Just use HtmlAgilityPack, you can then use something like `GetString`

Comment: do you need to download it or it comes with the standard c# library?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get plaintext from the response of a WebRequest class in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4279989/how-to-get-plaintext-from-the-response-of-a-webrequest-class-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Be more precise on your problem, give an example so we can help you better.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get all Display text from a webpage in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22138939/6138713)

Answer (score 1):

```
 You can use regex expressions for this. 

 Regex.Replace(htmltext, "<.*?>", string.Empty);

 Eg:- String htmltext = "string html = "<p>Test1 <b>.NET</b> Test2 Test3 
                         <i>HTML</i> Test4.</p>";"
      Output will be :- Test1 Test2 Test3 Test4.
```

This will help to you.
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/136704/Remove-all-the-HTML-tags-and-display-a-plain-text

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:** No direct conversion; you're "screen-scraping" a website; parse the result string to extract what you need (or better yet, see if there is an API provided by the website in question).

Websites render in HTML, not plain text. Although you're getting the result back as a string, you'll need to parse it to extract the text you are interested in. The actual extraction highly depends on what you are trying to accomplish. If the website is proper XHTML, you can load it into an `XDocument` as XML and traverse the tree to get the information you need; otherwise, the [HTMLAgilityPack](http://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack) suggested in one of the comments may be of help (not as magical as the comment is alluding to - it's a bit more work than `GetString`...)