# Getting plain text from HTML / deleting HTML tags from String in Android

Tags: android, html, string, parsing

I would like to display some content of a website somewhere in my app.
Here is an example of what input it will get:

```
<tr class='list even'><td class="list inline_header" colspan="6" >09e  Klasse 9e (Kla)</td></tr>
```

And it should output something like:

```
09e  Klasse 9e (Kla)
```

I have tried

```
text.replaceAll("<*>", "");
```

But it does not work the way I want.

*I am looking for the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40014750/how-to-convert-html-to-plain-text-c) question but for Java/Android.*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove HTML tags from a String](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/240546/remove-html-tags-from-a-string)

Comment: Oops, seems like this question has already been answered.

Answer (score 5):

You can try `Html.fromHtml()` instead `replaceAll()`

```
 String plainTextFromHTML = Html.fromHtml(TextsThatContainsHTML).toString();
```

or you can leverage both `Html.fromHtml()`  and `replaceAll()` like this

```
String plainTextFromHTML = Html.fromHtml(TextsThatContainsHTML).toString().replaceAll("\n", "").trim();
```